# Inline <input> and <div> not vertical aligned, though same height

Tags: html, css

**UPDATE:**
I think the best solution is one mentioned by Timothy Lee. In essence, add `vertical-align: top` to the `<div>` tag.

A label, an input, and a div walk into a bar...

These elements all have the following styles:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;
```

The div has a border and contains an anchor tag. The goal is to line the `div` and the `input` border, but it seems the `div` is 1px higher than the `input`.

See codepen for example

https://codepen.io/gosusheep/pen/PEQLOp

Thoughts on how to remedy this? I've mostly been messing around with margins and paddings and styling the anchor tag, but haven't found a solution.

Thanks for your time.

Edit:

P.S. 
I've spent a good amount of time googling and looking on stackoverflow for solutions (that's where I found the "line-height" explanation), but still can't solve it.

Edit2:

HTML:

```
<div class="my-container">
  <label for="text">Label</label>
  <input type="text" id="text" />
  <div class="my-link">
    <a href="#">suh dud</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-container {
  margin: 1rem;
}

input, label {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 40px;
}

.my-link {
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px black solid;
  line-height: 40px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.my-link > a {
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Please include all code relevant to the question, in the question itself. If Providing a [MCVE], use StackSnippets to do so when possible

Comment: How about to put the line-height:38 for the div button? Please see here; https://codepen.io/PigVicto/pen/govJaE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way, you can remove the div

```
<div class="my-container">
  <label for="text">Label</label>
  <input type="text" id="text" />
  <a class="my-link" href="#">suh dud</a>
</div>
```

and add `vertical-align`

```
.my-link {
  vertical-align:top;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px black solid;
  line-height: 40px;}
```

Comment: Ah. It seems that `vertical-align` works just fine on the anchor's container div. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

because the input element has inset border and your button has solid border, in second one, the solid element make a external border.
 Here two differents options for border-box >>>

```
border: 1px solid #000;
border: 1px inset #000;
```

Comment: Wouldn't `box-sizing: border-box` account for that?

If not, do you have a recommendation for a solution?

Create inset border for div, external for input, or something else?